# How to create an installer with self updates on windows server for an dotnet core console/service application

Tags: .net-core

I have an application, an aspnet core website 3.0 that is currently running in a console application.

A client is interested in installing it on their internal network.

I am thinking that its best to convert it to a background service and windows can ensure that its running. Following: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/07/creating-windows-services-in-net-core-part-3-the-net-core-worker-way/

What are my options to create an installer for this? Is there anything new out of the box with dotnet core that makes this easy, or should I just go with older "best practice" aka google it to create an installer? Or is it best to just use that `sc create TestService BinPath=C:\full\path\to\publish\dir\WindowsServiceExample.exe` command to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the blog post here. It really depends on who the target audience is. If it's someone trying to deploy it on an internal network, IMO the SC commands are fine because either

A. It's an IT person installing it anyway so they won't have fear of double clicking a .bat file.

B. The IT team uses some sort of GPO/scripting to keep all machines in line in which case they can surely run a one line command to install it anyway.

An installer is only useful if the end user is non-IT, a customer etc.